# "Property [registration_types] does not exist on this collection instance."

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code to show the next registrations of a user in a conference:

```
$nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()
          ->with('participants.registration_type')
          ->whereHas(
              'conference',
              function ($query) {
                  $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
              }
          )->paginate($pageLimit);
```

In the view I want to show a link "Get certificate" if the column "available_certificate" of the "registration_types" table has the value "Y".

But with the code below is not working, it appears "Property [registration_types] does not exist on this collection instance."

```
@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)

@if ($nextRegistration->participants->registration_types->certificate_available == 'Y')
    <a href="{{route('conferences.registrationInfo',['regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"class="btn btn-primary">Get Certificate</a>
@endif
@endforeach
```

For example if there is only 1 next registration $nextRegistrations shows:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#325 ▼
  ...
  #items: Collection {#319 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Registration {#320 ▼
      ...
        #relations: array:1 [▼
          "participants" => Collection {#307 ▼
            #items: array:1 [▼
              0 => Participant {#321 ▼
                ...
                #relations: array:1 [▼
                  "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#326 ▶}
                ]
                ...
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
 ...
}
```

Code in the view:

```
<ul class="list-group events-list">
    @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
        @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference) || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->date))
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <p>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->date->formatLocalized('%a, %b %d, %Y - %H:%M')}}</p>
                <h5>{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}</h5>
                <p> Registration {{$nextRegistration->created_at }}
                </p>
                @if ($nextRegistration->invoice == 'Y')
                  <!-- show some content -->
                @endif

                @if ($nextRegistration->totalPrice <= 0)
                    <!-- show some content -->
                @endif

                @if ($nextRegistration->status == 'C')
                   <!-- show some content -->
                @endif

                @if ($nextRegistration->status === 'I')
                    <!-- show some content -->
                @endif

            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: And what is error??

Comment: It appears "Undefined variable: nextRegistration" with "@foreach($nextRegistration->participants as $participant)" instead of "    @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)".

Comment: You must be change inside `@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration) ...code ... @endforeach`. See my updated answer

Comment: Ask about result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    @foreach($nextRegistration->participants as $participant)
        @if ($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')
            <a href="{{route('conferences.registrationInfo',['regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"class="btn btn-primary">Get Certificate</a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 
Thanks but the if in the question is already inside a  foreach "                                            @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
                                     @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)".
", that is used for example to show the conference title like "{{optional($nextRegistration->conference)->name}}".

Comment: `nextRegistration` has many  `participants`. Each `participant` has many `registration_types`, for this there has 2 `foreach`

Comment: A participant is only associated with a registration type, in the participant model is like "public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
    }".

Comment: Your initial question confused me `participants->registration_types`. It is incorrect In the first view i dont notice it

Comment: Thanks, but like that then appear "Undefined variable: nextRegistration" to show things like the conference name, also other information about the registration table like $nextRegistration->invoice to get the value stored in the invoice column.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with the code in the view to show that is necessary to get more info and with just "$nextRegistration->participants" it appears  "Undefined variable: nextRegistration".